# How to start Skype 4 with Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: skype

I've installed Skype and it's running all OK but I want it to start automatically when I log with my user.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want Skype to start when you login, you need to add it to "Startup Applications".

1. Open the Dash (hit the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, also called the Windows key)
2. Type *Startup Applications*.  It will look like this:

   [image]
3. Open "Startup Aplications" and click "Add".
4. A dialog will open with three fields: *Name*, *Command* and *Comment*.  Both *Name* and *Comment* are optional, the *Command* field tells Ubuntu what command to run when you login.
5. In the *Command* field put `skype` (all lowercase).
6. Click "Add" again.

[image]

Skype will now start when you login.

Once you log-in to your Skype account, make sure that you go into Options --> General, and check, Start Skype minimized in the system tray as shown below, that way Skype windows won't pop up on the screen once logged in.

[image]

Comment: Still works well on Ubuntu 13.10, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

I realized that this won't work, at least in Ubuntu 14.04. The app starts but no sound is present.

So, if you go to `/usr/share/applications` clicking on the Skype icon, you will find the right command to paste to startup applications.

This should be `env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U`

. Now you are ready to go! Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Open dash, search for startup applications, click the add button, put "Skype" in the name box, and "skype" in the command box, both without quotes.